# Calculating the determinant of a metric tensor

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

Suppose the line element is
$$ds^2 = -A(t,r)^2dt^2+B^2(t,r)dr^2+C^2(t,r)d\theta^2+C^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2.$$
Since the metric is diagonal, to find the determinant I can multiply the diagonal entries,
$$\det g_{ab} = g = -A^2B^2C^4 \sin^2\theta.$$
I have a few questions about this.

1. First off, why do we call the metric determinant $g$?
2. Why isn't it true that $g = g_{ab} g^{ab} = 4$? Isn't that how $g$ is defined?
3. When will it be true that $g = 1$?

Comment: It's just notation. We _define_ $g = \det g_{ab}$. In some texts, they use the definition $g = | \det g_{ab} |$ instead.

Comment: @Prahar Okay. But what if I write $g_{ab}$$g^{ab}$=$g$, is this correct?

Comment: $g_{ab} g^{ab}$ has nothing to do with the metric determinant. Think about it in terms of matrices; then $g_{ab} g^{ab} = \text{tr} (g^T g^{-1})$, which is something completely different.

Comment: @user2129579 - No. $g_{ab} g^{ab}$ has nothing to do with the determinant of $g$.

Comment: If you want to use index notation, the determinant of $g_{ab}$ can be written as $g\equiv\text{det}(g_{ab})=\epsilon_{i_0 i_1\cdots i_n} g_{0,i_0}g_{1,i_1}\cdots g_{n,i_n}$, where I have assumed the indices $a$ and $b$ run from $0$ to $n$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant for more details.

Answer (score 12):

> 1. First off, why do we call the metric determinant $g$?

Because we define the notation that way.

> 2. Why isn't it true that $g = g_{ab} g^{ab} = 4$? Isn't that how $g$ is defined?

If the determinant of the metric could be written using abstract index notation, without resorting to non-tensorial objects like the Levi-Civita tensor, then it would be an observable quantity that was a property of space at a particular point. There are such quantities: they're measures of curvature or related quantities involving derivatives of the curvature. But the metric itself (as opposed to its derivatives) doesn't let you compute a curvature, and therefore any such quantity that doesn't involve a derivative cannot be an observable.

What this tells you is that the determinant of the metric isn't a property of space, it's a property of the coordinates you've chosen. For example, if you use coordinates in which the basis vectors aren't orthogonal, then the determinant of the metric will be smaller.

> 3. When will it be true that $g = 1$?

Never, in 3+1 dimensions, because $g$ will be negative. If you want to know when $g=-1$, then the answer is whenever you choose coordinates that make that true.

Comment: Dear @user4552 Can you please explain how is $g$ negative?

Answer (score 1):

I will add something to 2.
First of all,

$$g \neq g_{ab}g^{ab}$$

but

$$ \delta g = gg^{ab} \delta g_{ba} $$

which you can prove from

$$ \partial_\mu(\det(A)) = \det(A)tr(A^{-1}\partial_\mu A) $$

which you can prove from

$$ \det \left( e^{B} \right) = e^{\mathrm{tr}(B)}$$